# Add value in textarea before existing textarea value

Tags: jquery

Currently when i click on Add Value it adds value after existing textarea value.
but i want it to add New Value before existing textarea value.

```
$('#add_value').click(function() { 
$(this).next().val($(this).next().val()+'New Value'); 
 });


<div id="add_value">Add Value</div>
<textarea>(want to add new value here) Existing value...</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(this).next().val($(this).next().val()+'New Value');
```

to:

```
$(this).next().val('New Value' + $(this).next().val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$(this).next().val($(this).next().val()+'New Value');
```

to

```
$(this).next().val('New Value' + $(this).next().val());
```

If you find yourself running into recursion issues, try storing the value before you work with it:

```
var thisVal = $(this).next().val();
$(this).next().val( 'New Value ' + thisval );
```

Answer (score 0):

I broke the individual logic steps out for readability.  This should do the trick, although did not test:

```
$('#add_value').click(function() { 
    var newValue = $(this).text();
    var currentValue = $(this).next().text();
    $(this).next().text(newValue + currentValue); 
});
```

The problem was your use of the jQuery val() method, which only works when trying to retrieve the HTML value attribute from form fields.  To grab the text contents of an HTML element use the text() method, or if you want to full html use html().

Then I simply concatenate the two values together.